# Conditional Merge Pandas Dataframe with Dataframe to add column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking to conditionally merge a summary dataframe that was value_count -ed:

`traitcount_df = traits_df['Trait_Count'].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False, ascending=True).to_frame()`

[image]

to the main dataframe:

[image]

I used this code originally but would like to be able to do it with the summary dataframe, first column acting as the key and conditionally loading.

```
rarity_conditions = [
    (traits_df['Trait_Count'] == 4),
    (traits_df['Trait_Count'] == 5), 
    (traits_df['Trait_Count'] == 6), 
    (traits_df['Trait_Count'] == 7)
    ]

rarity_values = [.0254, .2540, .5323, .1883]

traits_df['Trait_Count_Rarity'] = np.select(rarity_conditions, rarity_values)
```

Ive tried it with other dataframes unsuccessfully:

```
mouth_conditions = [
    (traits_df['Mouth'] = mouth_df[])
mouth_values = mouth_df['Mouth']
traits_df['Mouth_Rarity'] = np.select(mouth_conditions, mouth_values)
```

Comment: Is condition `(traits_df['Mouth'] = mouth_df[]` correct? Can you explain more `Ive tried it with other dataframes unsuccessfully` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can a lot simplify your solution:

```
s = traits_df['Trait_Count'].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False, ascending=True)
traits_df = traits_df.join(s.rename('Trait_Count_Rarity'), on='Trait_Count')
```

instead:

```
traitcount_df = traits_df['Trait_Count'].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False, ascending=True).to_frame()

rarity_conditions = [
    (traits_df['Trait_Count'] == 4),
    (traits_df['Trait_Count'] == 5), 
    (traits_df['Trait_Count'] == 6), 
    (traits_df['Trait_Count'] == 7)
    ]

rarity_values = [.0254, .2540, .5323, .1883]

traits_df['Trait_Count_Rarity'] = np.select(rarity_conditions, rarity_values)
```